# Парсинг URI на части php

Tags: php

Стоит задача пропарсить строку с GET параметрами.

Строка $get содержит различные гет парамерты, названия и значения которых я не знаю. Мне необходимо пропарсить строку так, что бы получить массив вида (key = value) тех параметров которые я знаю, к примеру utm_source, utm_medium, utm_term и другой массив где просто будут все оставшиеся неивестные параметры (к примеру param1=5&param2=6)

Возможно у кого-то есть уже похожая функция? Необходимо решение на php

Comment: ваше решение будет либо использовать строковые функции, например, `explode($url, '&')` а потом разбивки на ключ/значение, и подобные вариации, либо с использованием регулярных выражений. Другие варианты скорее всего будут уже включать сторонние библиотеки.

Comment: к комментарию @Visman добавить `array_flip` известных параметров, и `array_intersect_key` и `array_diff_key` и задача будет решена

Comment: @Visman действительно с этого вопроса можно почерпнуть нужное мне решение.

Comment: @teran благодарен за подсказки, я думаю дальше разберусь

Comment: для разбора строки в формате строки запроса URL используйте [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-str.php), `explode` грозит проблемами, т.к. надо будет учитывать экранирование, массивы  и пр.